# parsing site with reCAPTCHA using cURL

Tags: php, parsing, curl, recaptcha

So I have a site (`site A`) and have some data from this other site (`site B`) with a reCAPTCHA.

When trying to refresh data on `site A` from `site B` I'm blocked by the captcha.

So I'm trying to open `site B` in a new tab on same browser,

resolve the captcha then I'm hoping that I can retrieve the data and process it on `site A`.

When trying I get this error :

[image: reCAPTCHA error message]

I have admin access only to `site A`, `site B` is out of my reach.

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: First question: are you the owner / administrator of both site A and site B ?

Comment: Only site A not site B.

Comment: So you want us to help you get past security on a website you don't own? Seems to me that this site doesn't want people crawling it if you have to input a captcha just to view the page?

Comment: If site B uses [recaptcha v3](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2018/10/introducing-recaptcha-v3-new-way-to) then you probably cant. If the algorithm decided that you are a bot then its going to continue blocking you. (Thats the reason the owner of site B is using that addon/feature/plugin (whatever))

Comment: No, I want to check the reCAPTCHA so no security breach is done, I need to access the data on a page after solving the captcha